# Javascript and DataTables: Sort column with custom format

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net) to show data on a webpage. One of the columns has the following format:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
2.4
1.21
1.4
1.17
```

These values are not float numbers and I would like to sort them out the following way:

```
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.17
1.21
2.4
```

How can I do this? I tried with [this](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/sorting_manual) example but is not working. What I tried is the following:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['salary-grade-pre'] = function ( d ) {
    return parseInt(d.split(".")[1])
};
```

Comment: It works fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cxay5hz6/** I guess you have forgot to actually use the order function?

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks for your comment. The problem with that fiddle is when there are other numbers like 2.4

Comment: Then show some useful sample data and the problem as it is.  People cannot guess that your problem actually is Y when you describe a problem X .. No one understand "*but is not working*" as something *not* related to the question ...

Comment: @davidkonrad I added the number that I said to the question and I didn't added before because the first 100 records of my data starts with "1.x" and I actually didn't know it was failing with other numbers. And your comment of "is not working", I don't want to argue with you over here obviously, but it was unnecessary because i gave an example of the code that "wasn't working for me".

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this, it might not be the best, but works for what I need. I basically add a zero to those numbers that have 3 characters, i.e: 1.1 becomes 1.01 and then sort the values with their float number:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.type.order['salary-grade-pre'] = function ( d ) {
            if (d.length == 3) {
              d = d.replace(".", ".0")
            }

            return parseFloat(d)
        };
```